# Getting the view of an application

Tags: android, view

I am trying to create a SDK which the developer needs to pass the application context in order to work the SDK.

And I was wondering if it was possible to get the current View visible of the application with the Application context or with another workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I was wondering if it was possible to get the current View visible of the application with the Application context

No. After all, at any point in time, there may be zero, one, or many activities of the app visible (the latter limited to Android 7.0+). The `Application` singleton knows about none of them.

Comment: In this case, the developer should send the Activity to the SDK for this to be possible ?
Thank you also by the way :)

Comment: @Damiii: "the developer should send the Activity to the SDK for this to be possible ?" -- I do not know what your SDK is doing and therefore whether this will address your concern. It seems like a good starting point, though.

Comment: Is there some other advices that you could give it to me ? For example, another workaround to get the view of any activity ?
:)

Comment: @Damiii: "Is there some other advices that you could give it to me ?" -- not really. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you explain what your SDK will do, why it needs access to the root(?) `View` of an activity, and ask for suggestions.